# estimated marginal means mancova in R

Tags: r

I have calculated multiple dependent variables with MANCOVA using R, but I have difficulty with comparing group with multiple dependent variables, taking into account covariates. I want to use bonferroni test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. What did you try to solve this issue?

Comment: I used from code  emmeans_test(y2,postrunning~ group,covariate = prerunning, ref.group = "all",
             comparisons = NULL
             , p.adjust.method = "bonferroni",
             conf.level = 0.95, model = NULL, detailed = FALSE)     That's wrong  Error: 'vec_as_subscript' is not an exported object from 'namespace:vctrs'

Comment: this is code for one dependent and multiple covariates but I want compare means while I have multiple dependent and multiple covariate in moncova. I did a lot of searching but I couldn't find the package.   you can introduce with me book or link